# How to set hash key dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, hash

With this code,

```
h = {}
for (var i in [0,1]){ h[i.ToString] = i; }
```

I expected same result with `h["1"] = 1` and `h["2"] = 2`.

Why is this code doesn't work, and how can I define hash key dynamically in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for .. in` loop in JS iterates over keys, not over values (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
So in your case, you iterate over the keys of the array you have in there.
Those will be 0, 1, 2 ... no matter what you put in there.

What you could do instead would be something like this:

```
var obj = {};
var data = [1,2,3,4];
data.forEach(function(val) {
    obj[val] = val;
});
```